# Batch File - Copying contents of text file to clipboard

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, clipboard

I'm attempting to write a basic batch file to help with some tasks at work. Current iteration is as follows:

```
'@echo off
echo 1: Follow-Up Email
echo 2: Things
echo 3: Stuff

set /p "option=Select Option:"

IF %option%==1(
    type "C:\files\test.txt" | clip
    )
ELSE IF %option%==2(    
    type "C:\files\test2.txt" | clip
    )
ELSE IF %option%==3(
    type "C:\files\test3.txt" | clip
    )
ELSE (
    echo Not a valid option.
    )   '
```

Situation: text.txt contains the string "text123." text2.txt contains the string "test2." etc. My problem is the script simply does nothing. No text is put to the clipboard. What simple thing(s) am I missing?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Replace `type "C:\files\test.txt" | clip` with `clip < "C:\files\test.txt"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your else if syntax is the problem.  How about this?

```
@echo off

:Start
cls
echo 1: Follow-Up Email
echo 2: Things
echo 3: Stuff

set /p "option=Select Option:"

IF "%option%"=="1" type "C:\files\test.txt" | clip & goto :Done
IF "%option%"=="2" type "C:\files\test2.txt" | clip & goto :Done
IF "%option%"=="3" type "C:\files\test3.txt" | clip & goto :Done
echo.Not a valid option.
pause
goto :Start

:Done
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Now for learning time: Being exceptionally unskilled at programming in general, I'm trying to understand exactly why what I had didn't work. So you added :Start. Why was this necessary? What exactly does it do? I also see quotes around many things now. Why are the quotes required? What is the interpreter doing differently? Lastly, you changed the fourth to last line to echo.Not a valid option. Why is the period necessary?

Thanks much for your answers.

Comment: @Malaugrym You would consider to waste five minutes to open google to pick any of the thousands of Batch basic tutorials ...and read it.

Comment: 1. I added the label :Start so that you can jump to it if the user enters an invalid choice.  That is optional and you may decide to leave it out and then remove the goto :Start as well.  If you do that you don't need the cls to clear the screen either.  Comment too Long.. splitting)

Comment: 2.Quotes are not required in your case; but it is good practice to do it that way.  That way you don't accidently include spaces in the comparison and also the compare would work if the variable 'option' was not defined... which could not happen in your case.

Comment: 3. I used echo. for safety.  I never use echo followed by a space.  In your case it would work ok, but sooner or later you will do something like ECHO %option%  which will work fine until option is a space.  Then it will display ECHO is on.  or ECHO is off. (the state of the echo flag).  Having said that... I think one of the experts on this site has an excellent post describing why it is better to use ECHO) because ECHO. will cause unexpected behavior if you have a file named "." and also it may be faster.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Thanks for the advice. I have done that to quite a great extent. The point of my questions is that I find I learn a great deal more from people explaining things in the context of something I am familiar with, such as this code I attempted to write.

Comment: @RGuggisberg: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation. Makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code formatting was fubar.
The spaces before the ( in the if tests were missing,
and the placement of ELSE must be on the same line as the ) and (

It's not as robust as it could be, but it works.

```
@echo off
echo 1: Follow-Up Email
echo 2: Things
echo 3: Stuff

set /p "option=Select Option:"

IF %option%==1 (
    type "C:\files\test.txt" | clip
    ) ELSE IF %option%==2 (    
    type "C:\files\test2.txt" | clip
    ) ELSE IF %option%==3 (
    type "C:\files\test3.txt" | clip
    ) ELSE (
    echo Not a valid option.
    )
```