# BAT file programming assistance : how to make a response in a bat file copy to another part OR to clipboard?

Tags: batch-file

My apologies if the title was confusing. It should be fairly basic, but I cannot find a way to do this.

What i'm wanting to do is have a bat file prompt for an answer to a question and then surround that answer with another piece of code and either copy to the clipboard or after the connection.

Maybe it will make more sense if i give the code.

```
@echo off
set /p input ="what server would you like to connect to? (example srv02) :"
echo Myhome.%input%.com
pause
c:\program files\putty
```

the echo gives the correct response, but i would like to see if there is a way to paste this past the c:\program files\putty to connect to a server.

OR if there is a way to copy that response to the clipboard so the bat file would open putty (which it does now) and then you could just paste that response.

Or am i going about this the wrong way?  thanks for the help!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437749/batch-file-copying-contents-of-text-file-to-clipboard

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PuTTY user, so I can't be sure - But I believe you are simply trying to pass the the server host that you want to connect to. I think the following will do what you asked:

```
"c:\program files\putty" %input%
```

or

```
"c:\program files\putty" Myhome.%input%.com
```

However, there are probably other command line options you need to really accomplish your goal.

You should learn the [PuTTY command line arguments and options](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline). I suspect a web search could find some tutorials or examples to get you started.

Comment: Perfect! That is what i ended up doing after another few hours of research.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! That is what i ended up doing after a few more hours of research.

I came up with two different types of scripts as my company wants us to use a specific set of defaults for different servers.

```
@echo off
set /p input="what server would you like to connect to?  : "
echo myhome.%input%.com| clip
echo ----
echo myhome.%input%.com has been copied to your clipboard, 
echo you can now paste into the host name box in putty
echo -----
echo Press enter to open puTTY
echo -----
Pause
start c:\users\public\apps\putty.exe
```

Ended setting it to open putty instead of pasting because it should be defaulted settings, but not everyone kept it that way, of course.

Thanks for the assistance though!